# How can I define the argument name of an inner function in an outer function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

I have a function f_1 with different default input arguments, e.g. arg_1 and arg_2. Now I want to call f_1 with another function f_2 and change one of the default arguments, let us say arg_1. How can I tell f_2 that I want to change arg_1 in f_1?

```py
def f_1(arg_1 = x, arg_2 = y):
    some computations
    return result

def f_2(value_for_arg_f_1, name_arg_f_1):
    do some stuff
    out_f_1 = f_1(name_arg_f_1 = value_for_arg_f_1)
    do some more stuff
    return result_f_2
end_result = f_2(z, arg_2)
```

So looking in the example code - what do I have to write for name_arg_f_1 in f_2, such that (in the computation of end_result) out_f_1 = f_1(arg_2=z)?

Comment: `out_f_1 = f_1(arg_2=value_for_arg_f_1)`? It's hard to see the purpose of your code, unless it is confusing the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the example from [[Python 3.Docs]: Glossary - **argument**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument):

> ```py
> complex(real=3, imag=5)
> complex(**{'real': 3, 'imag': 5})
> ```

It relies on [[Python]: PEP 448 - Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448).

> ```py
> >>> def f1(arg1=1, arg2=2):
> ...     print("    Argument 1: [{:}], Argument 2: [{:}]".format(arg1, arg2))
> ...
> >>>
> >>> f1()
>     Argument 1: [1], Argument 2: [2]
> >>>
> >>> def f2(f1_arg_val, f1_arg_name):
> ...     f1(**{f1_arg_name: f1_arg_val})
> ...
> >>>
> >>> f2("value for argument 2", "arg2")
>     Argument 1: [1], Argument 2: [value for argument 2]
> ```

Comment: Thanks, that what I was looking for. I didn't know the ** input

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda functions, for example,

```
def adder(x=2, y=3):
    return x+y

adder()
# 5

adderEight = lambda y: adder(8, y)
adderEight(10)
# 18
```